# How to add and run multiple programs in IntelliJ project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I'm trying to add another class to an IntelliJ project I created. I already have one program in the project and it is running perfectly. I tried to add another program to the same project's `src` folder but cannot **Run** this file. The s/w allows me to build and compile the file but I'm only able to **Run** the first program I created in the project.

I could do this in Pycharm but not in IntelliJ. Am I missing something? Is there a different method to achieve this in IntelliJ?

Comment: add another run configuration.. it should be next to the run button. Click on Edit configurations and add a new one for your program.

Comment: `main method not found`. But I added a main method. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: I fixed it. Deleted and Rewrote the main method. Not sure why it didnt work though.

Answer (score 0):

You should press shortcut :<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.Then you could choose which program you wanna run.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on main method not found, it should bring you to the page where you can add the configuration.